# pundit_user: undefined method `current_user' for #<User:0x007fcefbc2b150>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, pundit

I have two layouts `Admin` and `Domain`. And I don't need any extra configuration in Admin layout. but if user tries to access `Domain` layout they must be in their valid domain.

This means that, I need to customize all of my `Domain` policy to include both `current_user` as well as `current_domain`. I found this can be done with `UserContext` and `pundit_user`... so here is what I have done:

`application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def pundit_user
    UserContext.new(current_user, current_domain)
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end

  def current_domain
    @current_domain ||= Domain.where(name: requested_domain).first
  end
  helper_method :current_domain

private

  def requested_domain
    return request.env["SERVER_NAME"]
  end

  def user_not_authorized
    # reset_session
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action"
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

Note that, when I access `Admin` layout, current_domain will be `nil` and if I visit any routes of `Domain` layout, then `current_domain` will set to currently accessing domain.

`user_context.rb`

```
class UserContext
  attr_reader :current_user, :current_domain

  def initialize(current_user, current_domain)
    @current_user = current_user
    @current_domain = current_domain
  end
end
```

### PROBLEM

Suppose I have this policy:

`user_policy.rb`

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :scope

  def initialize(user, scope)
    @user = user
    @scope = scope
  end

  def index?
    binding.pry # debugging
    current_user.admin? ||
    current_user.domain == current_domain
  end

private

  def current_user
    # return user.is_a?(User) ? user : user.current_user
    user.current_user
  end

  def current_domain
    # return user.is_a?(User) ? nil : user.current_domain
    user.current_domain
  end

end
```

when application runs `current_user` and `current_domain` must available in UserPolicy as per documentation(https://github.com/elabs/pundit#additional-context).

But I am getting

```
undefined method `current_user' for #<User:0x007fcefbc2b150>
```

That means, still I have user object in it, not `user.current_user` and `user.current_domain`

Please let me know, if you need further description. What am I missing here?

Comment: what version of Pundit are you using?

Comment: it's `pundit (1.0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

It was my own dumb mistake.

***PROBLEM***

I had a `before_filter` call in `domain/base_controller.rb` something like:

```
class Domain::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :domain_exists?
  before_action :verify_domain!

private

  def verify_domain!
    # PROBLEM: this line was updating pundit_user again to user object
    raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError unless DomainConsolePolicy.new(current_user, current_domain).authorized?
  end

  def domain_exists?
    if current_domain.blank?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Domain that you provided is not valid or is permanently removed!'
    end
  end
end
```

***SOLUTION:***

I have used `headless` policy for this because now I have both `current_user` and `current_domain` set with `pundit_user` in `application_controller`

`domain/base_controller.rb`

```
class Domain::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :domain_exists?
  before_action :verify_domain!

private

  def verify_domain!
    # SOLUTION
    authorize :domain_console, :has_access?
  end

  def domain_exists?
    if current_domain.blank?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Domain that you provided is not valid or is permanently removed!'
    end
  end
end
```

`policy/domain_console_policy.rb`

```
class DomainConsolePolicy < Struct.new(:user, :domain_console)

  def has_access?
    user.current_user.admin? ||
    user.current_user.domain_id == user.current_domain.id
  end

end
```

Thanks